# Does apple read the BLE device before they share the data with BLE devices?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

Does apple read the BLE device before they share/advertise the data with BLE devices? I am asking this question because I tried to connect the android device via Bluetooth to the iPhone. I am able to connect successfully but when I tried to subscribe notification characteristics but it is not found. I found one service which has five characteristics(3 unique) but none of them match with notification service and characteristics. I am matching with characteristics from the [ANCS document](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/AppleNotificationCenterServiceSpecification/Specification/Specification.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013460-CH1-SW7).

I am listing the three unique characteristics of UUID that I found:

1. 00002a05-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
2. 8667556c-9a37-4c91-84ed-54ee27d90049
3. af0badb1-5b99-43cd-917a-a77bc549e3cc

Is there any way that we can get to know what these characteristics do?